# Error in Stan Estimation of Generated Quantities

Tags: r, rstan

I'm trying to run an extension of V3 of the Imperial College London COVID model (their github repo is here: https://github.com/ImperialCollegeLondon/covid19model). The only things I've changed are adding data for the four large Canadian provinces to the data from the 14 European countries for which the model is built, and extending the forecast to 30 days into the future (the default is 7, but the code is designed to allow this kind of extension).

The core function of the model is to estimate expected daily death tolls based on country fixed effects and the interventions that are in place to slow down the virus. It also produces expected death tolls under a counterfactual scenario where no interventions are ever used (e.g. the only thing that affects death tolls is the predicted total infections and the infection fatality rate), in the generated quantities block of the stan code.

Every time I run it, though, I get warnings like these:

```
1: In validityMethod(object) :
  The following variables have undefined values:  E_deaths0[128,18]. Many subsequent functions will not work correctly.
```

E_deaths0 refers to expected deaths given no mitigation interventions on day 128, the last day of the forecast, in region 18 (June 2 in Quebec, in this case).

the code for generating these estimates is

```
E_deaths0[1, m]= 1e-15 * prediction0[1,m];
        for (i in 2:N2){
          E_deaths0[i,m] = ifr_noise[m] * dot_product(sub_col(prediction0, 1, m, i-1), tail(f_rev[m], i-1));
        }
```

Where prediction0[i, m] is the estimated infections on day i in country m, N2 being the total number of days to estimate (128). ifr_noise[m] is a modifier for the infection fatality rate in country m, and f_rev[m] is a vector of probabilities of dying on each day after being infected. There's no reason any of the elements that go into calculating E_deaths0 would ever be NA, and while prediction0 is estimated at 0 in a lot of samples for late dates and the later values of f_rev[m] round to 0, that doesn't seem like it should cause a problem because no division is happening.

This happens for different geographies each time. The dates also vary, although it's always the last n days of the simulation in a given region, with n between 1 and 8 or so. I assume the problem is in `sub_col(prediction0, 1, m, i-1)`, because `f_rev[m]` is data, so there's no potential for sampling issues, and if `ifr_noise[m]` were taking NA values then all dates for geography m would fail. I don't see how, though, because prediction0 is generated immediately before E_deaths0 and never causes warnings.

When I extract predictions of E_deaths0[128,18] or whichever estimates have problems in that run from the model fit, there are as many samples as I'd expect and they're all in a plausible range. I'm not sure whether I can trust those results, though, when the process to generate them throws random warnings.

Anybody have experience with issues like this, or any ideas? Thanks.

EDIT: here's the code for the model:

```
data {
  int <lower=1> M; // number of countries
  int <lower=1> P; // number of covariates
  int <lower=1> N0; // number of days for which to impute infections
  int<lower=1> N[M]; // days of observed data for country m. each entry must be <= N2
  int<lower=1> N2; // days of observed data + # of days to forecast
  int cases[N2,M]; // reported cases
  int deaths[N2, M]; // reported deaths -- the rows with i > N contain -1 and should be ignored
  matrix[N2, M] f; // h * s
  matrix[N2, P] X[M]; // features matrix
  int EpidemicStart[M];
  real pop[M];
  real SI[N2]; // fixed pre-calculated SI using emprical data from Neil
}

transformed data {
  vector[N2] SI_rev; // SI in reverse order
  vector[N2] f_rev[M]; // f in reversed order

  for(i in 1:N2)
    SI_rev[i] = SI[N2-i+1];

  for(m in 1:M){
    for(i in 1:N2) {
     f_rev[m, i] = f[N2-i+1,m];
    }
  }
}


parameters {
  real<lower=0> mu[M]; // intercept for Rt
  real<lower=0> alpha_hier[P]; // sudo parameter for the hier term for alpha
  real<lower=0> gamma;
  vector[M] lockdown;
  real<lower=0> kappa;
  real<lower=0> y[M];
  real<lower=0> phi;
  real<lower=0> tau;
  real <lower=0> ifr_noise[M];
}

transformed parameters {
    vector[P] alpha;
    matrix[N2, M] prediction = rep_matrix(0,N2,M);
    matrix[N2, M] E_deaths  = rep_matrix(0,N2,M);
    matrix[N2, M] Rt = rep_matrix(0,N2,M);
    matrix[N2, M] Rt_adj = Rt;

    {
      matrix[N2,M] cumm_sum = rep_matrix(0,N2,M);
      for(i in 1:P){
        alpha[i] = alpha_hier[i] - ( log(1.05) / 6.0 );
      }
      for (m in 1:M){
        prediction[1:N0,m] = rep_vector(y[m],N0); // learn the number of cases in the first N0 days
        cumm_sum[2:N0,m] = cumulative_sum(prediction[2:N0,m]);

        Rt[,m] = mu[m] * exp(-X[m] * alpha - X[m][,5] * lockdown[m]);
        Rt_adj[1:N0,m] = Rt[1:N0,m];
        for (i in (N0+1):N2) {
          real convolution = dot_product(sub_col(prediction, 1, m, i-1), tail(SI_rev, i-1));
          cumm_sum[i,m] = cumm_sum[i-1,m] + prediction[i-1,m];
          Rt_adj[i,m] = ((pop[m]-cumm_sum[i,m]) / pop[m]) * Rt[i,m];
          prediction[i, m] = Rt_adj[i,m] * convolution;
        }
        E_deaths[1, m]= 1e-15 * prediction[1,m];
        for (i in 2:N2){
          E_deaths[i,m] = ifr_noise[m] * dot_product(sub_col(prediction, 1, m, i-1), tail(f_rev[m], i-1));
        }
      }
    }
}
model {
  tau ~ exponential(0.03);
  for (m in 1:M){
      y[m] ~ exponential(1/tau);
  }
  gamma ~ normal(0,.2);
  lockdown ~ normal(0,gamma);
  phi ~ normal(0,5);
  kappa ~ normal(0,0.5);
  mu ~ normal(3.28, kappa); // citation: https://academic.oup.com/jtm/article/27/2/taaa021/5735319
  alpha_hier ~ gamma(.1667,1);
  ifr_noise ~ normal(1,0.1);
  for(m in 1:M){
    deaths[EpidemicStart[m]:N[m], m] ~ neg_binomial_2(E_deaths[EpidemicStart[m]:N[m], m], phi);
   }
}

generated quantities {
    matrix[N2, M] prediction0 = rep_matrix(0,N2,M);
    matrix[N2, M] E_deaths0  = rep_matrix(0,N2,M);

    {
      matrix[N2,M] cumm_sum0 = rep_matrix(0,N2,M);
      for (m in 1:M){
        for (i in 2:N0){
          cumm_sum0[i,m] = cumm_sum0[i-1,m] + y[m]; 
        }
        prediction0[1:N0,m] = rep_vector(y[m],N0); 
        for (i in (N0+1):N2) {
          real convolution0 = dot_product(sub_col(prediction0, 1, m, i-1), tail(SI_rev, i-1));
          cumm_sum0[i,m] = cumm_sum0[i-1,m] + prediction0[i-1,m];
          prediction0[i, m] = ((pop[m]-cumm_sum0[i,m]) / pop[m]) * mu[m] * convolution0;
        }
        E_deaths0[1, m]= 1e-15 * prediction0[1,m];
        for (i in 2:N2){
          E_deaths0[i,m] = ifr_noise[m] * dot_product(sub_col(prediction0, 1, m, i-1), tail(f_rev[m], i-1));
        }
      }
    }
}
```

The data is a list (called `stan_data`) with 17 elements:
*M, an integer equal to 18 in my version, 14 in the ICL model
*N, a vector of 18 integer values indicating the number of days of available data for each country
*deaths, a 135x18 matrix of observed daily deaths reported. Future dates are filled in with a -1
*f, a 135x18 matrix. Each entry f[i,m] indicates the probability of death on day i given exposure on day 0, given an assumed distribution of times from exposure to death and an estimated infection fatality rate from country m
*N0, an integer equal to 6 in both versions. The model seeds the infection by setting equal numbers of infections on days 1 to N0 based on samples parameter tau
*cases, a 135x18 matrix of detected cases per day in each country.
*SI, a vector of 135 double precision numbers. These represent the probability of spreading the virus to another person on each day, based on empirical data about the serial interval of infections (not published)
*EpidemicStart, a vector of 18 integers. The statistical fit of the model is based on fitting a negative binomial model to observed death counts from each country, from day = EpidemicStart[m] to date N[m] (i.e. from the day the epidemic started to the last day of observed data). Currently, in both the ICL version and mine, each entry of EpidemicStart = 31.
*pop, a vector of 18 integers with each country or province's population
*N2, an integer indicating the number of days to model. Currently set to 135 (from January 27th to 30 days from the last day of data)
*x, a vector of 135 integers counting up from 1 to N2
*P, an integer indicating the number of interventions to reduce transmission being modeled. Currently set to 6 in both versions of the model.

Comment: Which Stan interface is producing that message?  I haven't seen it before.  It would help to see the full model, specifically the loop over i and the size declarations.  But if `E_deaths[128, 18]` has a value, it looks like a false positive warning.  The general way to test if something's working is with simulated data where you know the answer and can check posterior coverage.

Comment: The model is built in R, with the Stan code executed through rstan. The warnings come up in the R console after the model is run.

Comment: The stan code can be found through the Imperial College github page here: https://github.com/ImperialCollegeLondon/covid19model/blob/master/stan-models/base.stan

Comment: Is that the model being run or the one you used as a basis for extension?  Is it possible to share your full model here with data sizes?

Comment: As of now, the stan code for the original version of the model and mine are identical. All I've done so far is to add data from four more regions. I've edited the post with the complete code and a brief explanation of the data used with sizes.